# Connection to Mongodb through Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, url

**Hii Everyone**

In my code, There is an API that works fine.
And I'm trying to connect to MongoDB from Node for the sake of inserting the data from the API.

As you can see, I get this error -
"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",
it looks like there is a problem with MongoClient.

I looked at the answers on this site about those topics and no one solves my problem.
Thanks for any help!

```js
let http = require('http');
let weatherKey = process.env.weatherKey;
// console.log(weatherKey);

function getData(cb) {

    http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=israel&appid=${weatherKey}`, res => {
        let data = ""
        res.on('data', string => {
            data += string
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            let obj = JSON.parse(data)
            cb(obj);
        })

    }).on("error", error => {
        cb(error);
    })
}

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

function connectToMongo(data)
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("weather-db");
    dbo.collection("node").insertOne(data, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("documents inserted");
        db.close();
    });
});

getData(connectToMongo);
```

Comment: Looks like a simply syntax error: `function connectToMongo(data)` is missing the `{`

Answer (score 0):

Your function is missing `{` after (data)

Comment: Please don't post answers to typo questions

Answer (score 0):

You were missing **{}** in your code.

```
let http = require('http');
let weatherKey = process.env.weatherKey;

function getData(cb) {

    http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=israel&appid=${weatherKey}`, res => {
        let data = ""
        res.on('data', string => {
            data += string
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            let obj = JSON.parse(data)
            cb(obj);
        })

    }).on("error", error => {
        cb(error);
    })
}

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

function connectToMongo(data){

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("weather-db");
        dbo.collection("node").insertOne(data, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("documents inserted");
            db.close();
        });
    });
}

getData(connectToMongo);
```